# Is the FTL homepage's DRM free version the gog.com one or another one?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

On http://www.ftlgame.com/ one can buy a DRM free version of FTL *plus* Steam key for $10 (the [Steam-alone version](http://store.steampowered.com/app/212680/) costs €10 = $13 in Europe), while on [gog.com](http://www.gog.com/en/gamecard/faster_than_light/) it's available for $9.99 (without Steam). Is the ftlgame.com DRM free version a gog.com gift key (thus including the gog.com bonuses), or "only" a DRM free exe?

Comment: Sorry @Joe, I absent-mindedly used the German plural of bonus...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version sold on FTLgame.com is not a GOG key, it's a standalone download for each platform. It is the same purchase/download system used by the [Humble Indie Bundles](http://www.humblebundle.com), if you have bought any of those. You get totally unrestricted downloads for each platform, and a button to fetch a Steam key, but none of the GOG.com extras.

A blog post on the official blog summarizes the different ways to buy: http://www.ftlgame.com/?p=378

Comment: Thanks! So if I want to have the full soundtrack, my best bet would be buying the game at http://www.ftlgame.com and then buying the soundtrack at Steam, or is it available separately?

Comment: There is a link on that blog page to the sound author's site where you can buy the soundtrack separately.

Comment: Thanks @ewanm89. Here's said link: http://benprunty.bandcamp.com/album/ftl Although in this case, Steam is slightly cheaper even in Europe (€3.49 instead of $5~€3.87)...